# How do I align a div to the bottom of another div (in bootstrap)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Related to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568829/how-do-i-align-images-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-in-bootstrap/15569397#15569397)

I would like to be able to align the pull-right div to the bottom of a div.

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer-images">
      <a href="link1"><img src="img1"></a>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="link2"><img src="img2"></a>
        <a href="link3"><img src="img3"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="copyright">
      <p>© Some Company YYYY</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to get the pull-right (or other div classes) to align to the bottom of the footer-images div class.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right. You just have to make sure you float the elements inside it (the  tags). But it will only be aligned from the top if you have different image sizes.

Would be much more easier to give you advice if you can show us an image of what you want to do and what does it look like as of now. (Would be better if you also show the css)